# How to eliminate the space before apostrophe (python)

Tags: python

For example:

```
print Var1,"'s value is X."
```

When I execute it, I get this:

```
Variable 's value is X.
```

You see that space after the e letter at the end of "Variable" word? How can I eliminate that? There isn't any space between the coma and the. quotations marks. Thanks.

Comment: If your variable is a string you can simply use a + instead of a comma.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use comma-separated arguments to print multiple items. Instead, build your desired string explicitly:

```
print "%s's value is X." % Var1
```

Comment: I get an error when I do that, it says the Variable is not defined. But I did define it...

Answer (score 3):

Use [string formatting](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string-formatting):

```
 print "{0}'s value is X.".format(Var)
```

or you can also use `print()` function(from py3.x) and pass `sep=""`(default value of `sep` is `" "`):

```
In [6]: Var1="foo"

In [7]: from __future__ import print_function

In [8]: print(Var1,"'s value is X.", sep="")
foo's value is X.
```

Comment: Sorry but I'm a complete newbie and that seems too complicated for me yet :) thanks though